# react native button click redirect screen error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, native

hi guys i wanted to navigate beetween screens so in my function components i used useNavigation for that ,but in my class component i cant use that  because its a react hook how can i do that on button click without usenavigation

this is my button component

```
 <TouchableOpacity style={{
                        backgroundColor: "#2a2e4a",
                        width: width - 40,
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        padding: 10,
                        borderRadius: 5,
                        margin: 20,

                    }}
                    >
                        <Text style={{
                            fontSize: 24,
                            fontWeight: "bold",
                            color: 'white'
                        }}>
                            PAGAR
              </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
```

and this is the function i want to implement to redirect the page

```
handlePayClick() {


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this as stated [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/#using-with-class-component) in official documentation.

```
import { TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

class MyBackButton extends React.Component {
  handlePayClick() {
    // Get it from props
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    navigation.navigate('YourScreenName');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          backgroundColor: '#2a2e4a',
          width: 40,
          alignItems: 'center',
          padding: 10,
          borderRadius: 5,
          margin: 20,
        }}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 24,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            color: 'white',
          }}>
          PAGAR
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

// Wrap and export
export default function (props) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return <MyBackButton {...props} navigation={navigation} />;
}
```